# Read many Matlab files, change them and create many new Matlab files in Python

Tags: matlab, python-3.x, save

Now the problem is how to put all the "new" matlab files in a Folder. Otherwise I am mixing the unswapped with the swapped ones. And my files are huge!

I wrote code, but even though I specify where to put the files, it does not work!

```
    read_files = glob.glob('/home/FeaturesF3/*.mat') 
    write_files = glob.glob('/home/Swapped/'
    x2D = np.array([])
    for f in read_files:
        x3D = sio.loadmat(f)['features']
        x2D = x3D.swapaxes(0,1)
        outputFileName = join (write_files, f + '_swapped.mat')
        sio.savemat(outputFileName, {"x2D":x2D})
```

I want to read many Matlab files (20) which are inside the folder "FeaturesF3", swap the indexes and then create other 20 new Matlab files. 
With my code, I only get 1 "*.mat" file. 
Where and how do I have to specify the name of the "new" Matlab files, and that there must be 20 and not just 1?

This is my code:

```
read_files = glob.glob('/home/FeaturesF3/*.mat') 
x2D = np.array([])
for f in read_files:
    x3D = sio.loadmat(f)['features']
    x2D = x3D.swapaxes(0,1)
    sio.savemat('/home/FeaturesF3/*.mat', {"x2D":x2D})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sio.savemat('/home/FeaturesF3/*.mat', {"x2D":x2D})
```

is your problem: you're always using the same file name (which, by the way, looks invalid).

What about simply appending to the input file name?

```
for f in read_files:
    …
    sio.savemat(f + "_swapped.mat", {"x2D":x2D})
```

Comment: Thank you. That make it work! But is it possible to create a new folder where to store the new files?